# Javascript number guessing game

Tags: javascript, numbers

I can't seem to make this code alert the user when the correct answer is found, nor can I make the pop-ups continue to loop to play again. I coded this as a learning exercise. In JS i'm very noob.

Can someone review my code and offer constructive criticism?

```
// noprotect

var targetNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

var userGuess = prompt("Pick a number from 1 to 100 to guess which one I'm  thinking about!" + " (6 guesses left.)");


for (var i=5; i>0; i--) {

if (i === 0) {
    prompt("Out of guesses!" + " (" + i + " guesses left.)" + " My number was: " + targetNumber);

}

if (isNaN(userGuess) === true) {
    userGuess = prompt("That value was not a number! Please pick a number from 1 to 100 to guess which one I'm thinking about!" + " (" + i + " guesses left.)");
}

if (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 100) {
    userGuess = prompt("That number was not between 1 and 100 inclusive! Please pick a number from 1 to 100 to guess which one I'm thinking about!" + " (" + i + " guesses left.)");
}

if (userGuess === targetNumber) {
    userGuess = alert("You're correct! My number was: " + targetNumber);
}

if (userGuess < targetNumber) {
    userGuess = prompt("You're too low, guess again" + " (" + i + " guesses left.)");
}

if (userGuess > targetNumber) {

    userGuess = prompt("You're too high, guess again!" + " (" + i + " guesses left.)");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add a quick note before I head home from the office. Your `for` loop will never allow `i === 0`condition to pass because the loop only continues if `i > 0`. You likely want to change this to `i >= 0` or adjust your conditions within the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing the string value `prompt()` returns with a number using `===`. That's not going to work.

Instead:

```
var userGuess = parseInt(prompt(...))
```

It's worth noting that `prompt` is an extremely clunky way to do this. What would be better is creating a form where you have a proper `<input>` field and a place to put the responses.